# sed con regex para cambiar contenido

Tags: regex, sed

Estoy con el dataset del Titanic y quiero aplicar varios cambios mediante sed o awk, pero quiero que tengan regex y que sean en varias líneas.

El dataset es así:

```
name,"gender","age","class","embarked","country","ticketno","fare","sibsp","parch","survived"
Abbing, Mr. Anthony,"male",42,"3rd","S","United States",5547,7.11,"0","0","no"
Abbott, Mr. Eugene Joseph,"male",13,"3rd","S","United States",2673,20.05,"0","2","no"
Abbott, Mr. Rossmore Edward,"male",16,"3rd","S","United States",2673,20.05,"1","1","no"
Abbott, Mrs. Rhoda Mary 'Rosa',"female",39,"3rd","S","England",2673,20.05,"1","1","yes"
Abelseth, Miss. Karen Marie,"female",16,"3rd","S","Norway",348125,7.13,"0","0","yes"
Abelseth, Mr. Olaus JÃ¸rgensen,"male",25,"crew","S","United States",348122,7.13,"0","0","yes"
Abelson, Mr. Samuel,"male",30,"2nd","C","France",3381,24,"1","0","no"
Abelson, Mrs. Hannah,"female",28,"2nd","C","France",3381,24,"1","0","yes"
Abi-Al-MunÃ , Mr. Nasif Qasim,"male",27,"3rd","C","Lebanon",2699,18.1509,"0","0","yes"
Abrahamsson, Mr. Abraham August Johannes,"male",20,"3rd","S","Finland",3101284,7.1806,"0","0","yes"
```

Quiero hacer un regex para hacer el cambio del campo "embarked" y lo planteo de esta forma:

```
sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z,.]*,[Mr|Mrs].[a-zA-Z]*,"[male|female]",[0-9][0-9],"[1st|2nd|3rd|crew]","C",/[a-zA-Z,.]*,[Mr|Mrs].[a-zA-Z]*,"[male|female]",[0-9][0-9],"[1st|2nd|3rd|crew]","Cherbourg",/g.' titanic.csv
```

Me da error al ejecutar `` sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 180: opción desconocida para `s' ``

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Comment: piensa que cuando usas `[male]` no estás buscando "male", sino indicando que haya un carácter de entre `m`, `a`, `l` o `e`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', soy consciente, pero entonces debería indicar ```"male"|"female"``` explicitamente en esa parte del regex? El mismo fallo lo cometo con ```[Mr.|Mrs.]```, no?

Comment: `sed -r 's/(una|otra)//'` debería funcionar. Fíjate en el `-r`.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Usando ```-r``` me da el error:```sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 88: opción desconocida para `s' ```. La expresión es: ```sed -r 's/[a-zA-Z,.]*,(Mr|Mrs).[a-zA-Z]*,"(male|female)",[0-9][0-9],"(1st|2nd|3rd|crew)","C",//"Cherbourg",/g.' titanic.csv``` Ten en cuenta que quiero usar Regex completo. No voy bien así?

Comment: Tienes un punto de más al final del todo, en `/g.`. Di solamente `/g`. También tienes una barra de más antes de "Cherbourg", es `,/"Cherbourg",/g`.

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular ha crecido mucho y hay distintos elementos que no funcionan.

Para que lo haga puedes usar algo así como:

```
sed -r 's/([a-zA-Z.]*, (Mr|Mrs).[ a-zA-Z]*,"(male|female)",[0-9][0-9],"(1st|2nd|3rd|crew)"),"C"/\1,"Cherbourg"/' fichero
```

Mírala poco a poco y cuando hagas pruebas ve añadiendo pieza a pieza poco a poco. Cuando funciona un bloque, añade el siguiente.

Por ejemplo:

- Para hacer coincidir la segunda columna es útil `, (Mr|Mrs).[ a-zA-Z]*`, que se basa en lo que hiciste tú y que añade:

  - `,` coma como delimitador
  - espacio
  - `(Mr|Mrs)` para indicar o bien "Mr" o bien "Mrs"
  - `.` para indicar cualquier carácter
  - `[ a-zA-Z]*` para indicar cualquier serie de letras y espacios

Fíjate también que he puesto un paréntesis "abrazando" todo lo que encajas y luego en la sustitución pongo `\1`. Esto lo que hace es coger el texto que ha coincidido con el patrón y volverlo a escribir despúes. Ejemplo simple:

```
$ echo "hola adios" | sed -r 's/^([a-z]*)/XX \1 XX/'
XX hola XX adios
```