# ¿Cómo selecciono un patrón y lo uso a la hora de reemplazar texto con Sed?

Tags: regex, sed

tengo un csv como el siguiente:

```
PassengerId,Survived,Pclass,Name,Sex,Age,SibSp,Parch,Ticket,Fare,Cabin,Embarked
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
891,0,3,"Dooley, Mr. Patrick",male,32,0,0,370376,7.75,,Q
```

Quiero hacer mediante `sed` el cambio con un regex de lo siguiente:

- Survived: 0= died / 1 = survived
- Pclass: 1=first / 2 = second / 3 = third

Cada `sed` quiero hacerlo en una línea independiente.

No sé por qué el regex no hace bien el cambio en 'survived'

```
sed -e 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9],1,/,Survived,/g' file.csv
```

Resultado: no cambia

```
1,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,22,1,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
2,1,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,38,1,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
3,1,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
4,1,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,35,1,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
```

He probado también con ````*``` ya que hay Id entre 1 y 900.

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]*,1,/,Survived,/g' file.csv
```

Resultado: no mantiene el dígito inicial

```
,0,3,"Braund, Mr. Owen Harris",male,,Survived,0,A/5 21171,7.25,,S
,Survived,1,"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)",female,,Survived,0,PC 17599,71.2833,C85,C
,Survived,3,"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina",female,26,0,0,STON/O2. 3101282,7.925,,S
,Survived,1,"Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)",female,,Survived,0,113803,53.1,C123,S
```

El resultado no es el esperado ya que no cambia ningún valor.
¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es guardar lo que encaja y volverlo a escribir, tal y como veíamos en [mi anterior respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/501481/83). Es decir, poner paréntesis alrededor de la expresión que encajas y luego escribirla de nuevo con `\1`:

```
sed -r 's/^([^,]*,)0/\1died/' fichero
```

Esto hace:

- Con `[^,]*,` busca cualquier carácter menos la coma, seguido de una coma
- Con `(...)` guardamos la expresión
- Luego `\1` lo escribe de nuevo

Comment: Me da error: ```sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 21: opción desconocida para `s' ```

Comment: ¿Qué versión de Sed usas?

Comment: @ fedorqui 'SO deja de dañar', versión 4.7